# How to solve this matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Lets say I have this

$H = W*F*W'$

where all matrices are 2x2 and $F$ is a diagonal matrix.

$H$ and $F$ is known. Ho solve get $W$ in algebraic form?

I tried this here:

$inv(W)*H*inv(W') = F$ but it seems wrong... Its not homework.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1:

You can pre-multiply both sides of an equation by the same conformable term.  So of you have

$$
X = AB
$$
you can do
$$
A^TX = A^TAB
$$
or 
$$
XB^T = ABB^T
$$

Hint 2:

If you have $X$ and you want to to go away, you can multiply it by $X^T(X^TX)^{-1}$

I suggest that you play around numerically to confirm the algebra.  Here's something to get you started:

```
W = matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2)
f <- diag(3:4)
H <- W %*% f %*% t(W)
```

Comment: When I follow your hints, I get $ inv(W)*H*inv(W') = F$, and it seems numerically to work on your example

Comment: That'll only work if W is square and invertible.  If it weren't, you'd need to do $W^T(W^TW)^{-1}$.  Which of course will also work where $W$ is square and invertible.

Comment: indeed... I dont understand what you say with "do". I tried  $(W'(W'*W)^-1)*H*inv(W')$ but it doesn't work

Comment: My problem seems to be that if W is symmetric, my solution does not result a diagonal matrix but instead gives a full matrix... Does your way result alway a diagonal F?

Comment: just take the diagonal.  It was never a vector anywhere except how you were thinking about it.  And I meant $W(W'W)^{-1}$ right-multiplied to $W'$ if you want to lose $W'$

Comment: Now I tried $inv(W)*H*(W'*(W'*W)^-1)$... unfortunately doest seem to work

Comment: Go back to algebra basics.  You need to multiply the same thing by both sides.  The only thing that changes with matrices is that it needs to be conformable and you need to respect the right vs left side.